# I don't have "Process" header

Tags: arduino-uno, linux

I'd like to run an application on my system after pushing a button on an Arduino shield. I've read that I need to use the `runShellCommand()` function, which can be accessed from a Process header. However when I add the `#include <Process.h>` line to my program I'm getting this error:

```
.build/uno/src/sketch.cpp:2:21: fatal error: Process.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Process.h>
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I've installed Arduino software from repositories.

Comment: Whatever unspecified guide you are following is at minimum incomplete, and probably outdated too.  Note that *nothing* you do in an Arduino sketch on an Uno is going to run commands on a Linux box, without help of software/configuration on the Linux box to accept them.  It may be better to come up with a program on the Linux box which waits for specific serial output from the Arduino sketch and then performs a preset command or operation.

Comment: "It may be better to come up with a program on the Linux box which waits for specific serial output from the Arduino sketch "  Can you suggest me how to do that or direct me to some guide about that ? I really need this functionality

Comment: Learn how to accomplish serial communication and subprocess execution in the programming language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

That only works on an Arduino Yún ([as described in this tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShellCommands)).